# Can I install redhat rpm on centos?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, openssl, centos-6

Can I install the Red Hat 6 version of the Openssl.rpm on the Centos6?

I am trying to backup and install an old version that can no longer be found in current repository.

I found the centos package file,
but I can't verify that it is not tampered with.

I have a redhat package file,
can I install it in centos?

Comment: Yes.  (Padding answer)

Answer (score 0):

Redhat, Centos and Fedora can interchangeably use the same RPM packages, matching the same version of course.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `rpm -qip [rpm-file]` to check the signature and integrity.
2. There are still CentOS6 repositories available via http://vault.centos.org local mirror (e.g. https://mirror.chpc.utah.edu/pub/vault.centos.org/ ) which house original packages and have all signatures published.